# Building a simple guessing game, iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I'm trying to build a simple guessing game. I'm having a weird problem:

```
-(int)setRandom {
    randomNum=(int)arc4random() % 100;
    return randomNum;
}

-(IBAction)submit
{
    num=[self setRandom];
    if([numberField.text intValue] > num)
        randomNumLabel.text=@"Too high. Try again";
    else if([numberField.text intValue] < num)
        randomNumLabel.text=@"Too low. Try again";
    else
        randomNumLabel.text=@"You got it, congrats!";

}
```

The problem is that I get a new random number every time I press submit. I thought that the first method would create the random number, and it would be the same every time, but apparently not. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this purpose you need a global variable.so first a fall declare

NSInteger num; in .h class then in `viewDidLoad` write like this

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

   num=[self setRandom];
  //you stuff
}
```

then in submit

```
-(IBAction)submit
{
    if([numberField.text intValue] > num)
        randomNumLabel.text=@"Too high. Try again";
    else if([numberField.text intValue] < num)
        randomNumLabel.text=@"Too low. Try again";
    else
       {
        randomNumLabel.text=@"You got it, congrats!";
         num=[self setRandom];
       }

}

-(int)setRandom {
    randomNum=(int)arc4random() % 100;
    return randomNum;
}
```

Here you get a random number at view load then you get new random number when your answer matches with the number.

So this will help you.

Answer (score 4):

Don't call setRandom every time in submit.  arc4random() returns a new random number every time you call it.

Create a property to store the random number and set it only when you need to -- in init and when the game resets.

Comment: Sorry I'm new to Objective-C, can you elaborate on how I can do this?